# Search and replace all field (CSV)

Tags: excel, csv

I have CSV file , and one of the field named 'Involved ST'.
This field can contain values like that:

**Before:**

```
Involved ST
V5 3rd
V4 3rd
V6 3rd
G140 2nd
G141 2nd
A2
A3
```

**After:**

```
Involved ST
 3rd
 3rd
 3rd
 2nd
 2nd
 1st
 1st
```

Now I have to replace each value that contain 3rd (like 'V5 3rd') in -> 3rd
Values that contain 2nd-> 2nd
Else replace with 1st.

Which tool can do that? Thank you!!

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you provide a clear "after" example to go with your "before"

Comment: How long is the ordinal list , i.e do you have XYZ 105th ? or do you not know?

Comment: no. just 1st , 2nd and 3rd.
if the string contain 3rd , I have to change the string value to 3rd.
if the string contain 2nd , change the string value to 2nd.
else change it to 1st.

Comment: And you need to preserve the CSV format? If so, how many lines are we talking about? And when you say field, it means your CSV data is multi column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the CSV in Excel you can use a formula like:

```
=IF(A2<>"", CHOOSE(IFERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(A2,3),{"3rd","2nd"},0),3),"3rd","2nd","1st"),"")
```

or

```
=IF(A2<>"", IF(ISERROR(MATCH(RIGHT(A2,3),{"3rd","2nd"},0)),"1st",RIGHT(A2,3)), "")
```

(assuming your values start in A2)

Comment: hi thanks , but it's not work. maybe I can do it with R language?

Comment: Maybe you can- I couldn't really know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try powershell - easily reads and writes csv and changing of values.

Comment: thanks.
maybe do you know which function there  equals to 'contain'?